# Get object from pointer C++

Tags: c++

I have a vector of objects (DimensionItem) and I want to push another item to the vector. I only have a pointer to the object I wish to push. How can I get the object from the pointer.

(New to pointers, very possible I'm am fundamentally misunderstanding something)

```
DimensionItem *selected_Item = dynamic_cast<DimensionItem*>(g_items[i]); //g_items is a list of items taken from my scene

vector<DimensionItem> DimItems;
DimItems.push_back(selected_Item);
```

The error message is:

no matching function for call to 'std::vector::push_back(DimensionItem*&)'

Comment: `DimItems.push_back(*selected_Item)`

Comment: If `selected_Item` is a pointer, you cannot add it to the container of objects. Instead, you must dereference the pointer with `*` operator.

Comment: Reopened because there is more than just dereferencing to this question.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want:

```
DimensionItem& selected_Item = dynamic_cast<DimensionItem&>(*g_items[i]); // Throws if g_items[i] is not DimensionItem.
vector<DimensionItem> DimItems;
DimItems.push_back(selected_Item); // Stores a copy of selected_Item.
```

`dynamic_cast<DimensionItem*>(g_items[i])` returns a null pointer if `g_items[i]` is not a `DimensionItem`, so the code would need to check the pointer for null before dereferencing it.

Whereas `dynamic_cast<DimensionItem&>(*g_items[i])` throws an exception in that case.

Comment: Since OP seems to be new to pointers, you should probably mention, that your code will create copy of original value.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski Done.